# persistent session through python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests to login a user from command line. I am also using `requests.session()` for persistence of the session.

```
>>> s = requests.session()
>>> s.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/accounts/login', auth=auth)
<Response [200]>
>>> l= s.post('http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/set_interests/', data={'skills': 'management'})
```

but the session is not giving me expected results. The login is successful but when i do this:

```
s.post('http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/set_interests/', data={'skills': 'management'})
```

It shows me that no user is logged in.
I also tried this:

```
>>> with requests.session() as s:
...   p = s.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/accounts/login/', auth=auth)
...   q = s.post('http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/set_interests/', data={'skills': 'management'})
```

But that is also showing the same results that no user is logged in.

What should i do to ensure persistence so that within that session it takes user as the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `requests.Session()`...not `requests.session()`.

More [in the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/).

Comment: ran into another problem. using this, it is showing dict object is not callable

Comment: even now with Session() , it is showing the same thing, no user is logged in